# Duplicated objects created in Blender Render are invisible in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I cannot figure it out. Perhaps you guys can help me out. I have created several objects in blender render, I forgot to switch to cycles at start. Anyways, the first object that I crearted shows up in cycles render, no problem. Any other objects (they were all duplicated meshes from the first object) are gone. I checked the visibility in outliner, all are listed as none under object->duplication. None has any textures applied, not even materials. Any help would he appreciated.

Blender file:
[image]

I tried to consult this thread, but no luck:
[Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67503?newreg=6d52e4ca4e5d4267943a3fe2209bb148)

[image: cycles render]

[image]
[image: blender render]

Comment: Hi Ryuu, it's a lot easier for people to diagnose problems if you post your blend file.

Comment: Cheers for such a quick reply, Dale. My bad, sorry, here is the link: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5152" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5152/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to Object properties, Cycles settings tab:

[image]

Turn on all Ray Visibility types:

[image]

Leave Shadow catcher unchecked.

But i will vote for close, becouse it's #5 from here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67503?newreg=6d52e4ca4e5d4267943a3fe2209bb148)

> 5. Cycles camera visibility disabled in object settings

Comment: I am embarrassed. That will teach me to read harder next time. Massive thanks for your help. One more question, though. Why is that one or two items had those options checked by default, and all others did not. Was it because they were duplicated from the original object? I am just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: By default all of them are checked, maybe you unchecked them and coped objects with this settings

Comment: I have not touched any of those check marks. All I did was creating objects in blender render from the start, that is it. Note that the first obecjt I created, which was the floor base, had all those check marks on, and that was by default, just like you said. All other objects were duplicates (shift D) of the main object. And all of those duplicates had all the check marks off. That was not done manually, so consequently, it seems that by default blender is unchecking those options for duplicates.I will try this out today and see. In any case, I really appreciate the help!